# html2canvas not working in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html2canvas

I'm trying to convert div element to canvas using **html2canvas** library inside **angularjs** controller, it throws no error in console but only gives an **empty** canvas, I included the html2canvas script in **master page** and the div element is inside a template page which is loaded using **ng-view**
the div element is

```
<div id="barcodeHtml" style="background-color: #82c6f8">
        <div style="width: 20%;float: left;display: list-item;"></div>
        <div style="width: 40%;float: left; align-content: center"> 
           <h2 style="display: inline;">CCAD</h2>
        <br>
        <div style="float: left;width: 50%">
            <h4>MEMBER NAME</h4>
            <h2>{{memberName}}</h2>
        </div>
        <div style="float: right;width: 50%"></div>

        <br>
        <br>
        <div style="float: left;width: 100%">
        <h4>MEMBER SINCE</h4>
        <h3>{{memberSince}}</h3>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br><br>
        <br>
        <img src="{{imgSource}}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
<a  class="btn btn-custom" ng-click="getCanvas()">get Canvas</a>
```

and the angular controller

```
$scope.getCanvas=function()
{
      $scope.memberName=data.html.name;
      $scope.memberSince=data.html.year;
      $scope.imgSource=data.html.code;
      html2canvas($("#barcodeHtml"), {
          onrendered: function(canvas) {
              document.body.appendChild(canvas);

          }
      });
}
```

what am I missing?
thank you in advance..

Comment: Not familiar with `html2canvas` but maybe it doesn't support jQuery object and should be passed a raw element instead as in `html2canvas($("#barcodeHtml")[0], {`

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and the result is the same

Comment: can you try with `document.getElementById("barcodeHtml")` ?

Comment: @anoop also the same

Comment: @FerasSalim: are you sure you get call inside `getConvas()` method and you don't have any console error?

Comment: yes I was able to debug it

Comment: @anoop this is the result:<canvas width="1366" height="0"></canvas>, surely I tried to set the height and also the same

Comment: @FerasSalim  try my answer

Comment: did you came across an issue like 'Uncaught (in promise) Provided element is not within a Document'  ?? My page has a side nav and i use ng-view to populate content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your `div` with `id="barcodeHtml"` does not have height so it is not able to append to the body.

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.getConvas=function()
   {
    html2canvas($("#barcodeHtml"), {
     onrendered: function(canvas) {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);

     }
    });
   }
  })
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div id="barcodeHtml" style="background-color: #82c6f8; height: 200px;">
   <div style="width: 20%;float: left;display: list-item;"></div>
   <div style="width: 40%;float: left; align-content: center"> 
    <h2 style="display: inline;">CCAD</h2>
    <br>
    <div style="float: left;width: 50%">
     <h4>MEMBER NAME</h4>
     <h2>{{memberName}}</h2>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right;width: 50%"></div>

    <br>
    <br>
    <div style="float: left;width: 100%">
     <h4>MEMBER SINCE</h4>
     <h3>{{memberSince}}</h3>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br><br>
    <br>
    <img src="{{imgSource}}"/>
   </div>
  </div>
  <a  class="btn btn-custom" ng-click="getConvas()">get Convas</a>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with your inline-styling.
I tried with removing `float: left;` from your upper `div` [from here : `<div style="width: 40%;float: left; align-content: center">`], then it worked.

See the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4w9rdrte/)